# Can my mini split disconnect be around corner of wall

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, mini-split

I am looking at locations to install my mini split outdoor unit. One location would be: you are facing the outdoor unit, on the right of the unit, the wall ends about 12 inches away and turns back away from you. On that wall I would like to put the disconnect about 2ft in (makes it easier from my inside sub panel). Is that still “within sight” by code. If you stand on the left side of the unit you can’t see it but if u stand on the right side of the unit you can. Sort of like the image below where line are the walls

```
       W | disconnect
       A |
       L | 
       L |
    Wall—-
Mini split
```

Comment: I believe it would comply. However this could be one of those times when it depends on the inspector and their interpretation of the code.

Comment: Your phrase "from inside sun panel" is a little vague and seems like you might have an issue with being "readily accessible". Might be good to read the text of NEC 440.14 here-> https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=1513.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needs to be line of sight from the unit, so anyone working on the unit can see that it's off/disabled.

Not "line of sight from only one side of the unit."